# How to use TouchableOpacity inside a Map Callout?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I have a component that I use for both the cells in my list results and for the detail callout in my map.

```js
// StationCellView

export default class StationCellView extends Component {
  onTextPress() {
    console.log("click text");
    this.props.navigation.navigate("UserDetail", { user: this.props.station.user });
  }
  onImagePress() {
    console.log("click image");
    this.props.navigation.navigate("StationDetail", { station: this.props.station });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.cellContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.textContainer}
          onPress={this.onTextPress}
        >
          <CellTextRow style={text.name}>{this.props.station.name}</CellTextRow>

          //...etc some more rows

        </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

// from MapResultsView

  renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <StationCellView station={item} navigation={this.props.navigation} />
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        style={{ marginLeft: 5, marginRight: 5 }}
        data={this.results}
        keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
      />
    );
  }
```

The `TouchableOpacity` works fine when I'm viewing the list. However, the `onPress` method isn't being called when the `StationCellView` is used inside a map callout:

```js
// from MapView

  renderMarkers() {
    return this.state.stations.map(station => {
      const logo = require("../assets/logos/BOLTIcon.jpg");
      return (
        <Marker
          coordinate={{
            latitude: station.location.lat,
            longitude: station.location.lng
          }}
          key={station.location.lat.toString() + station.location.lng.toString()}
        >
          <Callout>
            <StationCellView station={station}/>
          </Callout>
        </Marker>
      );
    });
  }

 render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          region={this.state.region}
          showsUserLocation={true}
        >
          {this.renderMarkers()}
        </MapView>
        <Callout style={styles.searchCallout}>
          <TextInput
            onChangeText={searchText => this.setState({ searchText })}
            // ... props ...
          />
        </Callout>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Please ignore, for now, the problems with calling `this.props.navigation.navigate` inside the press handlers. I've solved it in the list view and I'll fix it in the map view once I get the handlers to fire.

When I click the Touchables from the list view, "click text" shows up in the debugger console. When I click the Touchable from the map callout, nothing happens anywhere.

It may be noting that the first time I click the Touchable in the map, the opacity changes, but if I click it again, nothing happens.

I'm guessing there's some issue with the way maps and callouts work in the view heirarchy? Does anyone know?